# Does form processing code need to be abstracted? (Zend_Form)

Tags: php, zend-framework, refactoring

In Zend Frameworks tutorials, I can see form processing code like

```
if ($request->isPost()) {
            $formData = $request->getPost();

            $code = $request->getParam("code");
            $url = $request->getParam("url");

            if ($form->isValid($formData)) {
            // here goes code to determine insert/update action, 
            //retrive record data
            //and perform relative database operation
```

This code repeats for many forms. I am trying to make form handling better, yet not to over-engineer it. So far I have moved this code from Controllers into Form object.
But the code still diplicates for different form types.

My question is this - Should I prefer to keep form handling code duplicate or write some ProcessSubmit() Zend_Form method that will be used by all subclasses?
I had experience that abstraction is not always good and sometimes you end up synching two classes that shoul've been different from beginning.

ZF examples demonstrate duplicate code, so I wonder if this duplicity is justifed (at least for small 3-4 form sites) or needs to be avoided by all means.

P.S. This task seems to be pretty common, I wonder if I do double work and there is already a ZF class for CRUD specific form handling.

Comment: You should not move that code to the form class. That is clearly application flow and therefore it belongs to the controller.
What exactly do you mean by code duplication? The validation should happen automatically by calling `isValid()`, if you specify the fields in your form's sub class.

Comment: My intent to move processing of form controls into Form class was the concept of "thin controllers/fat models", e.g. http://blueparabola.com/blog/fat-models-are-good. Perhaps my mistake was to move code into Form while I should've moved the form/record processing into model. What do you think about this?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps an [action helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html) could, well, *help* you out here:

```
class App_Controller_Action_Helper_ProcessFormSubmit extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function isValid(Zend_Form $form)
    {
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            return $form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost());
        } else {
            return false;
        }        
    }

    public function direct(Zend_Form $form)
    {
        return $this->isValid($form);
    }

}
```

This allows you to handle form submission processing like this:

```
// or: if ($this->_helper->processFormSubmit->isValid($form)) {
if ($this->_helper->processFormSubmit($form)) {
    // here goes code to determine insert/update action, 
    //retrive record data
    //and perform relative database operation
}
```

This can be extended to your needs, e.g. automatic error handling and so on...

Answer (score 1):

What I have actually done was to move validation into the domain objects (or model layer), and then my domain layer implements a save() method.

While I don't use Zend_Form in my domain layer, I have noticed that others will implement a Zend_Form instance in their domain models so that they can present a consistent form everywhere for each domain model. Personally, I feel that this couples domain objects to the presentation layer too much.

Instead, I do use Zend_Filter_Input as the backbone for validation in my domain objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use "thin controllers/fat models" after validating the form just pass the whole form or form values to your model.

As for control structures in your controller they are "normal".